# Regex to match only the coordinate tuple in text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text sequence:

```
#76=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.,0.,0.));
#77=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));
#78=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.32,0.0999999999999997,1.));
#79=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,0.));
#80=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.32,0.0999999999999997,0.));
#81=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));
#82=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));
#83=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,0.));
```

And in this sequence, I want to extract the coordinates contained in the inner parentheses,
for example, I want to extract **(0.,0.,0.)** from the first line and so on.
For this, I am using the following regular expression:
`coords = re.findall(",\(.+\)", line)`
Please note that all this will be inside a for loop and hence the variable `line` would only contain a single line from that sequence above at a time.
The code that I write gives me the following output for the first line:
`,(0.,0.,0.))`

Is the expression I've written incorrect? What should be the right expression to only get the first ending parenthesis only?
Thank You.

Comment: Try using `\(\d.+?\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\((\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*)\)', test_str)
```

See [**Python proof**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasktbgkvrikSMFWoUhJ2dzM1tkxKMQ12NPRLz7A39MvRENdXUfDQE8HjDQ1rWPylM3NcSgyMAeqMbBEAeY6hjBtFji0GRvh1WZJkm0wR1oYkGQbXJshWX6zMCJPmzHpflPiKijKzCvRKErVS8vMS0nMydEoUo/R0IhJ0Y7Rs49J0dLUwcGO0VTXUYDFt6bm//8A):

```py
import re
test_str = r"#76=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.,0.,0.));\n#77=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));\n#78=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.32,0.0999999999999997,1.));\n#79=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,0.));\n#80=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.32,0.0999999999999997,0.));\n#81=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));\n#82=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,1.));\n#83=CARTESIAN_POINT('',(0.07,0.0999999999999997,0.));"
print(re.findall(r'\((\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*)\)', test_str))
```

**Results**:

```
[('0.', '0.', '0.'), ('0.07', '0.0999999999999997', '1.'), ('0.32', '0.0999999999999997', '1.'), ('0.07', '0.0999999999999997', '0.'), ('0.32', '0.0999999999999997', '0.'), ('0.07', '0.0999999999999997', '1.'), ('0.07', '0.0999999999999997', '1.'), ('0.07', '0.0999999999999997', '0.')]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/7wEVmG/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use

```
\([\d.,]+\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xIZM3a/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Any 1+ symbols except `(` and `)` inside `(` and `)`

```
\([^()]+\)
```